# Procedure followed when interviewing for Test Automation position

Tags: interview

I once attended an interview for the position of Test Automation Engineer. After being asked a few questions related to automation I was shown some screen shots of a login page, another web page with lots of links and menus etc. and then a log out page.

I was actually expecting some kind of GUI to write the test on but instead was asked to write, on paper the steps to automate certain areas as specified by the interviewer. E.g step to login, step access sub menu, verify certain text on the screen.

My question is what is the procedure followed by other companies out there when interviewing for the Test Automation position?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answerable question. How would you select a 'correct' answer for this question?

Comment: I am trying to gain more insight on procedures followed in other companies. I guess there is no one correct answer but any productive info will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

Companies vary in how they interview Test Automation people, just as they vary in how they interview for anything else.  Some places focus on general programming skills.  Some focus on test-specific technologies, e.g. Selenium and JMeter.  Some focus on testing skills, with the assumption that the automation skills are easy enough to learn that a general testing mindset is more important.  In that context, your interview experience sounds normal enough.